# Decrease file size of encrypted file

Tags: c#, security, memory-management, cryptography, base64

I am making a Cryptography application and I noticed that the encrypted file is approximately 2 times bigger because I am encoding the files in base64. Are there any file encodings that take less space? Here is the code that converts files into byte arrays:

```
Console.Write("Enter File Path: ");
docPath = Console.ReadLine();
extension = docPath.Substring(docPath.IndexOf(".")).Trim();
byte[] binarydata = File.ReadAllBytes(docPath);
text = System.Convert.ToBase64String(binarydata, 0, binarydata.Length);
var Encrypted = AESCryptography.Encrypt(text, m.ToString(), extension);
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(docPath.Substring(0,docPath.IndexOf(".")) + ".aent"))
{
    Byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(Encrypted);
    // Add some information to the file.
    fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
}
```

and here is the Encryption class that does the actual encryption:

```
public static class AESCryptography
{
    private const int keysize = 256;
    public static string Encrypt(string plainText, string passPhrase, string extention)
    {
        byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
        using (PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, null))
        {
            byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keysize / 8);
            using (RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                symmetricKey.GenerateIV();
                symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, symmetricKey.IV))
                {
                    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                        {
                            cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
                            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                            byte[] cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                            return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes) + "\n" + Convert.ToBase64String(symmetricKey.IV) + "\n" + extention;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static string Decrypt(string cipherText, string passPhrase, string initVector)
    {
        byte[] initVectorBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(initVector);
        byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
        using (PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, null))
        {
            byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keysize / 8);
            using (RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes))
                {
                    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes))
                    {
                        using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                        {
                            byte[] plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length];
                            int decryptedByteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
                            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, decryptedByteCount);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review.  We are not a code writing service, and as such, this question appears off-topic.  With that said, if you were to remove your request for help implementing new features, this seems like it'd be a perfectly on-topic question and we'd gladly review your existing code and help you fix it up a bit.

Comment: @nhgrif fixed it.

Comment: I feel this still needs more editing, **Are there any file encodings that take less space?** -> this looks like you are asking us to implement something or give you recommendations to implement something. Not sure if within the scope

Comment: I think the question is okay as it is. I consider it a performance question.

Comment: Do you have the option of compressing the incoming data before converting to Base64? Or is it already compressed? Or do you know?

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer it Might be compressed (jpeg for example)

Comment: Let's go one more - can you convert your incoming data from base64 to a byte array, then encrypt, then reconvert the encrypted bits back to base64? It looks like it's base64 incoming, which is bigger already, so converting back to binary would help.

Comment: 1) Base64 only increases data by a factor of 1.33 not 2. 2) Which encoding you can use depends on your requirements. In many applications you can simply output raw bytes.

Answer (score 2):

Let us analyze what the code is doing:

1. reading a file by calling `File.ReadAllBytes()`
2. converting these bytes to a base64 `String`
3. passing this `String` to the `Encrypt` method
4. converting the passed `String` to `byte[]`
5. encrypting this `byte[]`
6. converting the encrypted `byte[]` to `base64`
7. converting the `IV` vector to `base64`
8. returning the addition of `6.`, `7.` and the extension
9. converting the returned `String`to `byte[]` which is saved to a file with `.aent` extension

I can only see one reason why you want to do it in this way.

-> because you want to store the extension of the original file into the encrypted file.

Let us assume we don't want to store the extension of the original file inside the encrypted file, but we just append the `.aent` extension to the original filename.

This would have a lot of benefits. The code could be faster and the files could be smaller.

**Why so ?**

As [CodesInChaos](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/1482/codesinchaos) pointed out in the comments, Base64 increases the size of the data by 1.33 because for each 3 bytes you get 4 bytes back and the output is padded to always be a multiple of 4.
So starting with a file having a size of **1000 bytes** after `2.` you have **1336 bytes**. After the encryption the conversion to base64 of the encrypted data, only assuming you still would have **1336 bytes**, will result in **1784 bytes**. Now adding the to base64 converted `IV` vector, which has a size of 16 for the default `RijndaelManaged`, will result in additional **24 bytes**. The `\n` will result each in **2 bytes**.

So all together: 1784 + 2 + 24 + 2 = **1812** almost a factor of 2.

So let us skip the base64 converting and the adding of the file extension.

**Some remarks about the code**

- using of const for the keysize is **good**
- using proper casing for methodnames and parameter is **good** except `byte[] Encrypted`
- using the `using` keyword for using `IDisposable` objects is **good**

---

- using a parametername `plainText` but also stating it could be a `jpeg` file is **not so good**
- the way of getting the extension, instead of using built in methods is **not so good**

What you can do, but this is really a matter of taste, to reduce the indention of the code is stacking the `using` statements together like shown below. If we also extract the getting of the keybytes to a separate method, we loose one more indention and also the `Encrypt()` method gets shorter.

**Refactoring**

So let us start with the latter:

```
private static byte[] GetKeyBytes(string passPhrase)
{
    using (PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, null))
    {
        byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keysize / 8);
        return keyBytes;
    }
}
```

Now we will change the `String plainText` input parameter to `byte[] plainBytes` and the returntype to `byte[]`

But wait, as we get two `byte` arrays, one of the encrypted data and one of the `IV` vector data, we need to combine these to one array. So let us introduce a method first

```
private static byte[] Combine(byte[] first, byte[] second)
{
    byte[] ret = new byte[first.Length + second.Length];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(first, 0, ret, 0, first.Length);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(second, 0, ret, first.Length, second.Length);
    return ret;
}
```

And now the `Encrypt` method

```
public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] plainBytes, string passPhrase)
{
    byte[] keyBytes = GetKeyBytes(passPhrase);

    using (RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged())
    {
        symmetricKey.GenerateIV();
        symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

        using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, symmetricKey.IV))
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            cryptoStream.Write(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            return Combine(memoryStream.ToArray(), symmetricKey.IV);
        }
    }
}
```

If we want to decrypt this array, we need to get the last 16 bytes and use it as `IV` vector. The bytes till the last 16 bytes will then be the encrypted data itself.

Now, let us use the `Encrypt()` method

```
Console.Write("Enter File Path: ");
docPath = Console.ReadLine();
byte[] binarydata = File.ReadAllBytes(docPath);
byte[] Encrypted = Encrypt(binarydata, m.ToString());
File.WriteAllBytes(docPath + ".aent", Encrypted);
```

**Additional**

You really should check out the [System.IO.Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.Path%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class, as this class provides many helpful methods like `GetExtension()` for getting the fileextension, `GetFileNameWithoutExtension()` etc. .